# Nginx server returns 404 for all php pages except index

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, php7

I installed a new server with nginx and php 7.1. When I want to do a call to myurl.com/page it returns a 404. When I do a call to myurl.com/ everything is fine.

I already added this in my nginx config:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #       # With php7.0-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, stupid me. I had to add `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;` to my nginx config.